# remote SSH not working through USB ethernet adapter

Tags: usb, ssh, ethernet

1st off I'm very new to Ubuntu and Linux in general. However After playing around with a Raspberry Pi I was able to convert my old laptop in a server. Its been running great but the built in ethernet port is hit and miss and I tend to lose connectivity.

After doing some research I found a USB to ethernet adapter and it seemed my problems were solved. No connectivity drops and Plex/Ubooquity can be accessed remotely. One night I tried to remote in and connection was refused. I assumed it was configuration related and purged/re-installed both openssh-server and noip with no luck.

I can ssh on network, and reach plex, ubooquity etc. remotely. But remote SSH is refused. But if I move the ethernet cable back to the default ethernet port it works perfectly! Any ideas? I feel its something simples I've overlooked.

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Comment: Is the laptop getting the same IP on both ports when you are moving the ethernet cable back and forth?  Usually a DHCP server will assign each one a different IP since they are different MAC Addresses.

Comment: Terrance is right.  It might pay to check your modem/router to see what IP port 22 is forwarded too, and make sure the IP address on the USB Ethernet is the same. It's unlikely that the USB adapter will have the same IP as the onboard Ethernet.

Comment: Nailed it Terrance! My SSH port was only forwarding on the ethernet port and not the adapter. Never thought to check since some services were working and only remote SSH was failing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Per Terrance's recommendation I check port forwarding configuration and noticed the adapter and ethernet had different IPs. Once I enabled port forwarding for the ethernet adapter I was again able to connect via remote SSH.